# sklearn FeatureHasher parallelized

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

sklearn's `Featurehasher` feature extractor has several advantages compared to its `DictVectorizer` counter-part, thanks to using the hashing trick.

One advantage which seems harder to tap is its ability to run in parallel.

My question is, how can I easily make `FeatureHasher` run in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a parallel version of `FeatureHasher.transform` using `joblib` (the library favoured by scikit-learn for parallel processing):

```
from sklearn.externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

def transform_parallel(self, X, n_jobs):
    transform_splits = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, backend="threading")(
        delayed(self.transform)(X_split)
        for X_split in np.array_split(X, n_jobs))

    return sp.vstack(transform_splits)

FeatureHasher.transform_parallel = transform_parallel
f = FeatureHasher()
f.transform_parallel(np.array([{'a':3,'b':2}]*10), n_jobs=5)

<10x1048576 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 20 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: DictVectorizer takes a list of dictionaries into a numpy array. Any parallel method would need to make sure it was consistent between splits.    How could you ensure this consistency?

Comment: @eleanora we're not fitting in parallel, we're transforming in parallel, the mapping of dictionary keys to vector indices is already set, and all the worker threads will get this same mapping

Comment: (you would have to train the vectorizer first of course, this wasn't included in the example above because you don't need to fit the `FeatureHasher`)

Comment: @maxymoo while you're right, this is exactly the reason i switched from DictVectorizer to FeatureHasher. If I were to do the same with DictVectorizer I were not able to process the same amount of data precisely because I had to initially fit it sequentially.